# Xamarin android-support-multidex.jar issue. How to get that file?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, android-multidex

I tried all the solutions I could find online, but nothing helps. Here is the error I get when I try to build my project (on MAC OS X):

> "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
>   Error: Error executing task CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries: Could not
>   find file
>   "/Users/marianbusoi/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar".

I enabled the Multidex option for the project and installed the Android Support Repository, as some people suggested, but that jar file still isn't there. The Android Support Repository files are somewhere else (extras/android/m2repository), and inside the containing folder I can't find that jar file either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. See this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65064/how-to-add-the-multidex-jar-in-the-xamarin

Make sure you have Android Studio installed.

Then, launch SDK Manager and try checking the box to show obsolete libraries and getting **Android Support Library** in addition to the **Android Support Repository**.

cd Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/

Make the directories if you don't have them with

> mkdir -p /extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/)

Once you are in there, copy the android-support-multidex.jar.

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/instrumentation/libs/android-support-multidex.jar

Comment: I am having library in the android sdk folder... ??.. But still facing classdefound error

Comment: Worked after copying the file in the specified location. Xamarin expects a speicific location, but Android SDK downloads the file in a different location and file type ".aar". So I extracted the aar to zip -> copied the classes.jar renamed to android-support-multidex.jar and pasted the jar in the above location